# XML namespace definition for recursive element

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have xml that is defined such as

```
<metadata>
  <data name="a">
    <data name="a1">
      <data name="aa1" value="aa1"/>
    </data>
    <data name="a2" value="a2"/>
  </data>
  <data name="b">
    <data name="b1" value="b1"/>
  </data>
  <data name="c" value="c">
</metadata>
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around namespaces and recursion in XSD...
Could someone help me defining the namespace

Comment: The duplicate link answers your question in general.  If you require more specific help, read [ask], then [edit] your question to add a [mcve] and a specific question about where you're stuck, not an [*overly broad general plea for help*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085).

Comment: It would also be a good idea to accept answers to the some of 15 questions you've asked in the past year.  If you're not getting helpful answers, again, read [ask] and improve your question asking skills.